# Out-Gridview removes underscores

Tags: powershell, out-gridview

Consider the following code:

```
$a = @()

$b = "" |select ho_ho,ha_ha
$b.ho_ho = "1"
$b.ha_ha = "2"
$a+=$b

$b = "" |select ho_ho,ha_ha
$b.ho_ho = "3"
$b.ha_ha = "4"
$a+=$b

$a | Format-Table -AutoSize
$a | Out-GridView
```

Using Format-Table, the underscores on the column headers are retained.

```
ho_ho ha_ha
----- -----
1     2
3     4
```

However, when using Out-Gridview, the underscores are automatically removed?

[image: Underscores removed]

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to the fact in WPF that the first underscore in a text prefixes the accelerator character for the control.

See this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/permanenttan/2008/01/22/wpf-equivalent-for-winforms-ampersand-to-prefix-accessaccelerator-character/) for details:

> WPF uses an underscore character instead of the ampersand character
>   (like with WinForms) to prefix an access (a.k.a. accelerator or
>   mnemonic) key in the text of its elements like Label and Button.
>
> You can escape the underscore by using two underscores.

So this code would display Ok in the gridview but not in the `Format-Table` output

```
$a = @()

$b = "" |select ho__ho,ha__ha
$b.ho__ho = "1"
$b.ha__ha = "2"
$a+=$b

$b = "" |select ho__ho,ha__ha
$b.ho__ho = "3"
$b.ha__ha = "4"
$a+=$b

$a | Format-Table -AutoSize
$a | Out-GridView
```

Please note that the escaping is only necessary on the first underscore in the string, not the others.

I think this may be regarded as a bug (since it's not actually adding any key shortcuts either), but I couldn't find any reports on http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Excellent find (nice feature-bug :) ). Actually it does add key shortcuts if you use a different letter after the 1st '_'. E.g.: `(1,'c'),(2,'b'),(3,'a') | Select-Object -Property @{Name='ab_cd'; Expression={$_[0]}}, @{Name='ef_gh_ij'; Expression={$_[1]}} | Out-GridView`. When you press Alt, 'c' & 'g' will become highlighted. Pressing Alt+C or Alt+G will sort by that column (alternating between Ascending & Descending).